# Tensorflow how to do l2 regularization manually without function for it and using add_loss?

Tags: tensorflow, loss-function

I have to build a l2 regualarizer without the use of tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer. Instead I have to use the given hint:
tf.losses.add_loss and to the collection tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES.

I am new to tensor flow and don't have any idea on how this can be implemented. It will be great if someone can help me. I am working on python 3.6
I have no idea what should loss be in the code written below

```
"""First layer of the neural network.

Args:
    net: 2D tensor (batch-size, number of vocabulary tokens),
    l2_reg_val: float -- regularization coefficient.
    is_training: boolean tensor.A

Returns:
    2D tensor (batch-size, 40), where 40 is the hidden dimensionality.
"""
l2_reg = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(l2_reg_val)   
net = tf.nn.l2_normalize(net, dim = 1)
net = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
        net, 40, activation_fn=None,biases_initializer=None)#, weights_regularizer=loss)
output = l2_reg_val*sum(net ** 2) / 2
net=tf.losses.add_loss(output, loss_collection=tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES)
```

Comment: Please improve formatting of your question. Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Now it's completely unclear what are you trying to do. You need to add l2 to weight/bias tensor? Or you need to add all the losses to your loss function?

Answer (score 0):

`tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer` basically just applies `tf.nn.l2_loss`. So you either can apply it to your weights,

```
W = tf.get_variable('W', dtype, shape=[input_dim, num_units], initializer)
```

or use its formula `output = sum(W ** 2) / 2` 
`tf.nn.l2_loss` doesn't add it's output to loss collection. So you need to do it manually.

```
l2 = tf.nn.l2_loss(W)
tf.losses.add_loss(l2, loss_collection=tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES)
```

After that you can inspect the contents of this collection with

```
tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES)
```

or

```
tf.losses.get_regularization_loss()
```

And add this loss to your main loss function. Hope this makes it clearer

Comment: This is what I have updated my code to. I still don't find it accurate. I am very new to tensorflow sorry if my questions are really stupid. I have put he updated code in the question above. Also I cannot use tf.nn.l2_loss directly.

Comment: Glad to hear. If this answer was helpful, please consider accepting it